# Input value in Java program from shell script

Tags: java, sh

I wanted to know if there is a way, from a `sh` script, to input value in a Java program. For example I have a `program.jar`. I do `java -jar program.jar` and it outputs:

```
Enter your name:
```

Would it be possible to write an `sh` script like that:

```
java -jar program
echo name
```

where `name` is gonna be the input for the program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To echo data into your java program from the shell do something like this:

```
java -jar program<< EOF
<your-data>
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@tcb 's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809970/input-value-in-java-program-from-shell-script/7810004#7810004), you can also use a standard input redirection pipe `<` in order to specify a file that will be the input of the program:

**input.txt**

```
name
```

And in the `sh`:

`java -jar program < input.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Use pipes:

```
echo name | java -jar program
```

Comment: Isn't that `cat name`? Surely if the input was literally "name" then the OP would have already understood to write `java -jar program name`.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean interactive input , [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) is always one of the answers.